# Creating lots of random cuts on a surface

Tags: modeling, edges

Here's an image of a cube with lots of edges added. It was created using knife tool and lots of clicking:

[image]

What would be the best way to randomly generate such cuts with less effort...?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rereading the question and answers, there is actually a third way to do this that's very very quick if you just want the surface tessellation. (i.e. you dont want the cuts to be separate objects or meshes)

Make a cube, apply subdivision surface on it (simple, 2 levels), then use the  Decimate modifier to reduce the polygon count and apply the modifiers from bottom to top.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

The cell fracture tool should do what you require.
Press <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and search for 
`CELL FRACTURE`

.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Continuing off of AdamTM's answer. Cell fracture creates a lot of separate objects. To get to just cuts on the surface takes a few more steps.

1. Merge all of the fractured objects together <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.
2. In edit mode select all of the exterior faces and then use
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection.
3. Use <kbd>X</kbd> to delete all of the interior geometry by deleting
   the vertices.
4. Remove doubles to fix all of the overlapping vertexes at the outer
   seams.

My final result looks like this:
[image]